# How to capitalize button text pre-Lollipop?

Tags: android, textview, android-button, android-styles, android-textattributes

I tried using adding it into styles.xml like so:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Main theme colors -->
        <!--   your app branding color for the app bar -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <!--   darker variant for the status bar and contextual app bars -->
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
        <!--   theme UI controls like checkboxes and text fields -->
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>

        <!-- buttons will not have shadows -->
        <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless</item>
        <item name="android:textAppearanceButton">@style/DefaultButtonTextStyle</item>

        <item name="android:colorBackground">@android:color/white</item>

    </style>

<!--The button text style to be used throughout the app-->
    <style name="DefaultButtonTextStyle" parent="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Button">
        <!-- Ensure that the buttons are all caps even pre Lollipop-->
        <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
        <item name="textAllCaps">true</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to create a custom style for your button

```
<style name="CustomButton">
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_centerVertical">true</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
</style>
```

Then set it to your button like:

```
<Button 
     android:id="@+id/total_bill"
     style="@style/CustomButton" />
```

Or you can do something like:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="buttonStyle">@style/MyButton</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyButton" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
        <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
    </style>
```

The second method will change it for all Button across the application.One another way is to extend the Button and create a custom Button where textcaps is set to true and use that Button instead of default one.

Comment: I am assuming <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item> should be <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>

Comment: That worked! I was doing that earlier but instead of <item name="buttonStyle">@style/MyButton</item> I was doing <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/MyButton</item>.

When do you prefix "android:" and when do you not?

Comment: For android specific names you will use android:.For custom theme name there is no need to use android:.